# Javascript eval() Exception - line number

Tags: javascript, exception, eval, node.js, v8

In JavaScript I have a `var str = ".a long string that contains many lines..."`
In case of exception that caused by `eval(str);`

I had like to catch it and print the the line number that caused the exception. (the line internal to str..)

Is it possible?

**EDIT** As part of the Alligator project (http://github.com/mrohad/Alligator), an application server for JavaScript, I am reading files from the disk and eval() anything that is nested to a scriplet( < ? ? > )

I am running this script outside a browser, using NodeJS (on top of V8).

Comment: Not sure this can be done at all without splitting the multi-line command into separate instructions and eval() calls.

Comment: It's pretty ugly to use "eval" in the first place. Perhaps you could describe what you're trying to do, and somebody might have a better idea.

Comment: The problem with splitting the eval to multi lines is for example when you have if(cond) <- line #1 {some code} <- line #2, line 1 will throw exception since it depends on line #2

Comment: I assumed that in an age of AJAX someone would want a solution to this. I am having the same [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265371/how-to-properly-generate-exceptions-in-php-dojo-when-returning-javascript-code)

Comment: @MrOhad - checkout this Google V8 issue http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1914

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution which is pretty inefficient, yet I only use it when debug_mode==1 so it's not that bad..

I write the eval_str to a file, I "import that file, and invoke it inside a try{}catch{} and I parse the error line from the stack trace...

In my specific case, this is how the code looks like:

```
var errFileContent = "exports.run = "+evalStringAsAFunction+";";
fs.writeFile('/home/vadmin/Alligator/lib/debugging.js', errFileContent, function (err) {
    var debug = require('./debugging');
    try{
         debug.run(args...);
    }
    catch(er){
         log.debug(parseg(er));
    }
});
```

Comment: This is an inefficient hack, but it's definitely a workaround until Google V8 supports this feature. Nice, thx.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding the try/catch to the string instead of around the eval:

```
var code = 'try{\nvar c = thisFuncIsNotDefined();\n}catch(e){alert(e.lineNumber);}';
```

Comment: I thought it's even better than my solution, but I have tested it and it doesn't work, same stack as if the try{} catch{} wasn't part of the eval

Comment: combine this with the solution from @AndreyKo and you have a solution that will work in Firefox

Comment: also doesn't work if the string has a syntax error, because the try/catch isn't even able to be constructed properly to catch the error!

Comment: The question was about **NodeJS** with which this answer **doesn't work**. `e.lineNumber` is `undefined` there.

Answer (score 3):

1) Run:

```
var javascript_offset;
try {
  undefined_function();
} catch(ex1) {
  javascript_offset = ex1.lineNumber;
}
try {
  YOUR_STRING_WITH_JS
} catch (ex2) {
  var line_that_caused_it = ex2.lineNumber - javascript_offset -2;
  HANDLE_THE_EXCEPTION_HERE
}
```

Comment: I am running this script outside a browser, using NodeJS (on top of V8)

Answer (score 0):

```
replaceErrors(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof Error) {
      var error = {};
      Object.
        getOwnPropertyNames(value).
        forEach(function (key) {
          error[key] = value[key];
        });
      return error;
    }
    return value;
  }
const errorStr = JSON.stringify(error.stack, this.replaceErrors);
const regexp = 'your reg';
          let isHasLineNum = regexp.exec(errorStr);
          let lineNum
          if (isHasLineNum) {
            lineNum = isHasLineNum[0];
          }
```

Comment: https://harrymoreno.com/2017/02/25/how-to-read-a-javascript-stack-trace.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

This solves your problem?

```
try {
    eval(str);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.lineNumber)
}
```

Comment: @MrOhad, the `lineNumber` property on Error objects is *non-standard*, it will work only on Mozilla implementations, but I'm afraid that it will return you the line number where you invoked `eval`, not the actual line number inside the evaluated text.

Comment: Works in Firefox, but not other browsers. In Chrome/Iron, you can get the row number close to the end of `e.stack`.

Comment: e.stack doesn't return undefined yet it does return the line of the eval and not the line internal to the eval string

Comment: Can you say what does e contain?

Comment: Sure:
message: aasas is not defined; 
stack: ReferenceError: aasas is not defined
    at eval at serverSideScripting (/home/vadmin/Alligator/lib/jssp.js:262:4)...;
type: not_defined; 
arguments: aasas; 
name: ReferenceError;

Comment: e is an exception. In firefox it has many properties, like: fileName, lineNumber, message, name and stack. Why I get -1?

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The question asks if you can get the line number inside the eval'ed text, not the line number where eval() was called.

Comment: @BMiner, this answer is not correct. It doesn't work consistently in all JS environments. `e.lineNumber = undefined` in NodeJS for example. And the question was exactly about NodeJS.

Comment: V8 has long been fixed so _runtime_ errors inside eval() show `<anonymous>:LINE:COLUMN` of where it happened inside the eval'd code (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=1914).  E.g. that part works for me on NodeJS 18. However _SyntaxError_ stack still reports caller of eval() :-(