# Synchronous <script> statements?

Tags: javascript, eval, synchronous

I am using `xmlhttprequest` (and `eval`) to dynamically load scripts. Next I evaluate the script and look to see if there are any other scripts to load. Along the way if any of the scripts cause and exception, the error message reported indicates the line number associated with `eval`, not with the actual error in the script.

On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869957/is-there-any-way-other-than-to-use-eval-handleas-javascript-to-dynamically-f/7869989#7869989) it was suggested I use `<script>` instead to get better error messages. Unfortunately, `<script>` is asynchronous, and I won't be able to control the order of loading of scripts (I need an `onload` callback).

How do I implement synchronous behaviour in `<script>` commands

---

Some more info as to what I aim to achieve

Every script has a list of other scripts it loads, stored in a list, lets call it `_toLoad`

Lets say we have a script 'Main.js' with a load list like so

`_toLoad = [['A.js'] , ['B.js'] , ['C.js'] , ['D.js' , 'E.js' , 'F.js']]`

Which states that once loaded, the file 'A.js' must be loaded next. Once 'A.js' is loaded, 'B.js' must be loaded next. Once 'B.js' is loaded, 'C.js' must be loaded next. Once 'C.js' is loaded, 'D.js' ,'E.js' , and 'F.js' must be loaded, in any order.

I could use `<script>` to load 'Main.js', evaluate it's `_toLoad` list and start loading the other scripts, in the correct order. But what happens if 'A.js' has several scripts it also loads? I want those to load in the background, and not to delay 'B.js' from loading

What if 'A.js' has a load list like so:

`_toLoad = [['A2.js'] , ['B2.js'] , ['C2.js'] , ['D2.js' , 'E2.js' , 'F2.js']]`

Is I would have to go through and issue `<script>` statements for those. It seems like a depth first approach, when I want a form of breadth first.

Comment: Scripts [can't really be loaded synchronously][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously

Comment: I haven't used it (yet) myself, but [YepNope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) may help. I know it is described as an asynch loader, but it gives control over when the scripts are executed, so...

Comment: `<script>` tags embedded in your page are loaded asynchronously (for faster loading speed) and executed sychronously.  Do you have to load the script via Ajax?

Comment: @jfriend00 I think I worded the question incorrectly. I am using Ajax to dynamically and asynchronously load in scripts (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265371/how-to-properly-generate-exceptions-in-php-dojo-when-returning-javascript-code)). But that uses `eval` and debugging is a nightmare. So it was [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869957/is-there-any-way-other-than-to-use-eval-handleas-javascript-to-dynamically-f) I try using `<script>` but with a sort of `onload` callback

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking why you are loading them using Ajax?  If you want sychronous, `<script>` tags embedded in your page give you that automatically.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry, the reason is that `<script>` tags [don't have onload callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously)

Comment: You're not understanding my question.  If you use `<script>` tags embedded in your page (not loaded dynamically), then the browser will automatically execute them sychronously for you - you don't have to do anything.  You don't need onload events.  I've asked you multiple times WHY you are loading them via ajax which is causing this async issue in the first place and you seem to be avoiding answering that question.

Comment: @jfriend00 the reason is that I need control. Script A might load scripts B , C , D. Furthermore, it might specify, for example, B be loaded first, then C and D. Script B then might load scripts B1, B2, then after both are loaded, load scripts B3-B10. Every script has a list like so `_pre = [[A] , [B , C] ,...]` so I load it, evaluate the list (`_pre`) and continue loading as necessery. But --and this answers your question-- I want the execution to be asynchronous (I just realized my wording was wrong). I don't want to load the scripts 1 at a time, but still want to know when they have loaded

Comment: Here's how you can load scripts dynamically and know when they are loaded: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4479/discussion-between-puk-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the linked questions mentioned setting the innerHTML of the script tag element. I think this might [do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/missingno/EsTg2/)

```
function load(toEval, callback){
    __global_callback = callback;

    var node = document.createElement('script');
    node.innerHTML = toEval + '; __global_callback()';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}

load("console.log('before...');", function(){
    console.log('...and after');
});
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want me to get the script via Ajax, as I have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265371/how-to-properly-generate-exceptions-in-php-dojo-when-returning-javascript-code) (`handleAs: "text"` instead of `'javascript'`) then build the script from that. Essentially it's the same as `<script src=...>` except we omit the source and include the code as the body. Right?

Comment: Yes, that would be the idea (I don't know how robust or cross browser it would be though)